# Configure exchange email account via Android API

Tags: android, api, email, exchange-server

I'd like to write an application that, given a username and password, will (among other things) configure an exchange email email account on the device. Is it possible to do via the Android API? If so, via what class?

Comment: If you figure out any ways to do something similar on the latest version 4.0 please let me know or post your solution here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570905/exchange-account-configuration-on-android-4-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the versions prior to 3.0 there is a way to configure exchange email by passing in the UserName and Password as extras.

```
ComponentName cname = new ComponentName("com.android.email", "com.android.email.activity.setup.AccountSetupBasics");
            Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
            intent.putExtra("com.android.email.AccountSetupBasics.username", emailAddress);
            intent.putExtra("com.android.email.AccountSetupBasics.password", config.password);
            intent.putExtra("com.android.email.extra.eas_flow", true);
            intent.setComponent(cname);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I tried to use this code but I getting exception "Activity not found" :/, I am running it at android 2.3.6 ...

Comment: Which phone is it?? May be they have a custom email client??

Comment: It is nexus one. I am getting error "Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.email/com.android.email.activity.setup.AccountSetupBasics}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?"