# Exchange account configuration on android 4.0

Tags: android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

The early versions of android had a way by which Exchange account could be automatically configured through an app - by feeding in the email and password.

The android 4.0 email application had changed a lot.
Any reference as to how it can be done on the latest version?

Comment: do you have the sample code or link/article where we can refer exchange account configured automatically/programmatically prior to version 4.0? I'll let you know if I find some source for 4.0 as well. Thanks

Comment: @dackyD See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901653/configure-exchange-email-account-via-android-api